# Picture inside excel cell?

Tags: excel

Do you know how can I make excel cells  [look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNl0A.png)?

When I change the color of some of these cells to for example yellow, than this picture disappears, but If I choose "no fill" option, then I again get this picture as default cell look.

I think that this is not a picture inserted into cell, because when I click on the cell, I don't get "format picture" options in the ribbon. These cells behave like normal excel cells.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks as if the sheet has set a background which comes from a picture (image) -> See [Add or remove a sheet background](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-remove-a-sheet-background-3577a762-8450-4556-96a2-cc265abc00a8).

And all cells except those on column `H` have a white fill in cell interior -> See [Add or change the background color of cells](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-change-the-background-color-of-cells-ac10f131-b847-428f-b656-d65375fb815e).

Comment: I suspect: Page Layout tab, click the Background button.